# What is the difference in sense between wollen and wollten

Tags: modal-verb, tense

I understand that one is the indicative and the other is the subjunctive, but I often hear that wollen is used when someone intends to do something while the subjunctive form is used when someone wants to make a suggestion in an unsure manner (less certain than möchten)

examples as I understand it:

- Ich wollte Kuchen essen - I wanted to eat cake (but I'm not sure about it)
- Ich will Kuchen essen - I intend to eat cake (no matter what anyone says)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, one of the problems with the *Verb* "wollen" is that there is no direct counterpart in the english language. Your example sentence:

> Ich will Kuchen essen.

Could either mean "I *intend* to eat cake" as you mentioned, but it could mean "I *want* to eat cake." Notice that the former somewhat implies there is cake available whereas the latter can be said regardless of cake being there or not.

A second problem is that "wollte" could be one of two forms: *Präteritum* or *Konjunktiv*.

> Ich wollte Kuchen essen.

This is mostly interpreted as *Präteritum* if it stands on its own: you wished (wanted, intended) to eat cake, but that was somewhere in the past. The *Konjunktiv* (subjunctive) would usually require some clause, i.e.:

> Ich wollte Kuchen essen, sofern einer da ist.

"I'd eat cake if some is there" or "I'd want to eat cake if some is there". Or, without such a clause, in questions:

> Wer wollte nicht Kuchen essen?

"Who wouldn't want to eat cake?" or "who wouldn't eat cake?"

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the full [Wiktionary table](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:wollen), *wollte* is ambiguous, it can mean subjunctive or past, and the exact meaning depends on the context.

Where uniqueness is required, typically for the subjunctive as the less frequently used form a different phrasing is used instead, like *Ich hätte Kuchen essen wollen*.

Answer (score 0):

Modal verbs in German have a so called *subjective use*. In indicative, it's for assertions and in Konjunktiv II for assumptions.

> Thomas will keinen Alkohol mehr trinken.

Well, Thomas wants to but his internist says no.

> Thomas wollte keinen Alkohol mehr trinken.

That was a New Year's resolution he gave up quickly.

Comment: I understand your second example as past tense. For subjective, I’d think of sentences like “ich wollt‘ ich wär ein Huhn”.

Comment: It's not about the past but about fiction. Präteritum and Konjunktiv II are two sides of the same coin. That's also why they can easily share forms and no one sees a problem.